# Running docker-compose up with ProcessBuilder succeeds, but ProcessBuilder not returning result

Tags: java, docker, jar, docker-compose, processbuilder

I am running docker-compose up with ProcessBuilder and everything works fine in my machine. I am getting the started image details by reading the stream o/p. 
Now I have packaged this inside a jar and added to another project as maven dependency. The command works fine, but i am not able to get any details back. ProcessBuilder streams looks empty. But i could see that docker images are running.

I have combined both input and error data. But both are empty. 
As a workaround I am running below command,

```
docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}
{{end}}' <<container name>>
```

in ProcessBuilder , which is working fine if i run directly on a terminal, but that also not returning the IP address.

```
public List<String> execute(String directory, String command) {
        List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
        commands.add("bash");
        commands.add("-c");
        commands.add(command);
        Process dockerComposeCommand;

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO();
        builder.command(commands);
        builder.directory(new File(directory).getParentFile());
        String path = System.getenv("PATH");
        builder.environment().put("PATH","/usr/bin:"+path);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        builder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            dockerComposeCommand = builder.start();
            dockerComposeCommand.waitFor();
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dockerComposeCommand.getInputStream()))) {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    result.add(line);
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I want to get the details of the containers from ProcessBuilder, which I am getting in my local machine

Comment: That IP address is basically useless in many contexts.  Never look it up.  From outside the container you should connect to your host’s IP address (or `localhost` if and only if you’re running outside of Docker on the same physical host) and the first port number from a `docker run -p` option.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze. but how do i make sure that my containers are up ? Should I go only with the exit code of ProcessBuilder ?

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution for the same. I just commented inheritIO() as shown below.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();//.inheritIO();
```

One more point is , if you have inheritIO() in your code, the output will be printing in the console of the calling program.

As @DavidMaze mentioned , these ips are of no use. So I have added another method to check the status of docker container.